# Moving an existing TFS project to GIT on TFS with the same name

Tags: git, tfs, version-control, migration

We have a project on TFS (TFS 2015) that we would like to move to Git on TFS. We would like to keep it in the same TFS collection. The TFS server is on premise.

### Things we would like to achieve:

- We would also like to keep the same name of the TFS project.
- We would also like to possibly bring across the work items and history.

### So far this is the best plan we have come up with:

For this example, let's call the project **acme**.

1. Rename the **acme** to **acme_old**.
2. Create a new project called **acme-git**
3. Use git-tf and follow the instructions on this [blog article](http://juristr.com/blog/2015/03/migrate-tfs-to-git/).
4. This involves, cloning and creating a git tag for each the changesets.
5. Adjusting the committer names.
6. Push to server.

### Issues

We would like to keep the same name obviously, but when we try to change to the original name - **acme** - we get an error saying:

> The Team Project name acme was previously used and there are still TFVC
>   workspaces referring to this name. Before you can use this name, the
>   owner of each workspace should execute the Get command to update their
>   workspaces.

The project (and root of the collection) are associated to workspaces on peoples machines. Some still work here, some have moved on.

We can delete the workspaces using [tfs-sidekick](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) for the workspaces of the people no longer working here. As far as we can tell, the rest need to all do a get on all the projects in their workspace.

## Is there are better way to do this migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a new team project. You can create a Git repository within the same Team Project that contains your TFVC repository.

Comment: If OP is already on TFS 2015 Update 1 or later (see https://www.visualstudio.com/news/tfs2015-update1-vs#git).